# Python: Merge two dataframes skipping some rows w.r.t. to column value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

Have got dataframe *df1* and *df2* as below:

*df1*

```
Item        Space
Grape       0.125
Mango       0.125
Mango       0.125
Beetroot    0.125
Beetroot    0.125
Beetroot    0.125
Carrot      0.125
Carrot      0.125
Carrot      0.125
Carrot      0.125
```

*df2*

```
Table_No    Part    Dedicated_Item      
1           1       null                    
1           2       null                
1           3       null                
1           5       Potato      
1           6       null                
1           7       null                
1           8       null                
2           1       null                
2           2       Onion
2           3       null                
2           5       null                
2           6       null                
2           7       null        
2           8       null
```

Need to merge `df1` and `df2` only to rows with '`null`' value in '`Dedicated_Item`' column in `df2`.
Note: Both `df1` and `df2` row order should not be changed. To be added as such. If df2 got extra rows left as such.

***Expected Output:***

```
Table_No    Part    Dedicated_Item      Item        Space
1           1       null                Grape       0.125       
1           2       null                Mango       0.125   
1           3       null                Mango       0.125
1           5       Potato      
1           6       null                Beetroot    0.125
1           7       null                Beetroot    0.125
1           8       null                Beetroot    0.125
2           1       null                Carrot      0.125   
2           2       Onion
2           3       null                Carrot      0.125
2           5       null                Carrot      0.125
2           6       null                Carrot      0.125
2           7       null        
2           8       null
```

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `null` are NaNs, you could use:

```
idx = df2[df2['Dedicated_Item'].isna()].index
df2.loc[idx, df1.columns] = df1.set_axis(idx[:len(df1)])

# or for a new dataframe:
# new = pd.concat([df2, df1.set_axis(idx[:len(df1)])], axis=1)
```

If you have literal `null` strings, use:

```
idx = df2[df2['Dedicated_Item'].eq('null')].index
```

output:

```
    Table_No  Part Dedicated_Item      Item  Space
0          1     1            NaN     Grape  0.125
1          1     2            NaN     Mango  0.125
2          1     3            NaN     Mango  0.125
3          1     5         Potato       NaN    NaN
4          1     6            NaN  Beetroot  0.125
5          1     7            NaN  Beetroot  0.125
6          1     8            NaN  Beetroot  0.125
7          2     1            NaN    Carrot  0.125
8          2     2          Onion       NaN    NaN
9          2     3            NaN    Carrot  0.125
10         2     5            NaN    Carrot  0.125
11         2     6            NaN    Carrot  0.125
12         2     7            NaN       NaN    NaN
13         2     8            NaN       NaN    NaN
```

Comment: It's not working as expected. Instead new columns get added to same row as expands. Like for same Table_no=1 and Part=1 all Items from df1 gets added up.

Comment: @user12345 I didn't understand what is not working. It seems fine with the provided data. Please clarify or provide a better example.